# mysqli php problems showing orders in groups / SELECT DISTINCT shows only one result

Tags: php, select, mysqli, count, distinct

I'm having some trouble with my php / mysqli code, hopefully you can help me. 
I'm currently working on an online shop for a school project. Customers are able to buy things, they get an order number and I'm writing their user_id, the order number, the different products and some other things in a relation.
now the administrator should be able to see all orders. 
right now it looks like this (I copied my table into a word table, so it's easier to see the structure):

[part of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imRa2.jpg)

So the problem is that I have two different order numbers (80425 and 14808) and I want to show each number (and the name and adress of the custumer, too) only one time, but for each order number all different ordered products.
I imagine it like this:

[part of the table (more organised)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKpLZ.jpg)

(it's german, I hope you still get what I mean)
So this is the code right now for getting all the information and show them in a table:

```
$selection = "SELECT * FROM kundenbestellungen, zahlart, produkte, user, status_bestellung, wohnsitz, kontodaten
                WHERE b_zahlung_id = z_id
                AND b_produkte_id = p_id
                AND b_user_id = u_id
                AND b_status_id = sb_id
                AND w_user_id = u_id
                AND d_user_id = u_id";
$sql = mysqli_query ($dblink, $selection) OR die (mysqli_error($dblink));
if (mysqli_num_rows ($sql) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php /*Change the status to sent*/  
            if ($row['b_status_id'] == '0') {
                echo $row['sb_status'];
                ?>
                <form action="admin-bestellungen.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['b_id']?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="versenden" value="versenden">
                </form>
            <?php
            } else {
                echo $row['sb_status'];
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['b_nummer'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['u_vorname']." ".$row['u_nachname'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['p_produktname'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['b_menge_produkt'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['b_einzelpreis'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['z_art'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['b_zeitpunkt'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
}
```

I'm really confused. I tried this below the $selection part, just to start with something:

```
$anzahl_bestellungen = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b_nummer) AS nr FROM kundenbestellungen";
$anzahl_bestellungen = mysqli_query ($dblink, $anzahl_bestellungen) OR die (mysqli_error($dblink));
$bestell = mysqli_fetch_array($anzahl_bestellungen);

print_r($bestell['nr']);
```

and the code counts the amount of the different order numbers (8). But if I use it without COUNT, it shows only the first order number (80425) and also counts only 1 result and doesn't get the other 7 numbers.

```
$anzahl_bestellungen = "SELECT DISTINCT b_nummer FROM kundenbestellungen";
$anzahl_bestellungen = mysqli_query ($dblink, $anzahl_bestellungen) OR die (mysqli_error($dblink));
$bestell = mysqli_fetch_array($anzahl_bestellungen);

print_r($bestell['b_nummer']);
$b = count($bestell['b_nummer']);
echo "<br>".$b;
```

I also tried to work something out with GROUP, but then the code shows only one item for each order number.
I tried to work with a for-loop as well, but that didn't work out either.
I thought about a multidimensional array, but I wasn't able to think through that whole thing, I'm not very good at php / mysqli.
So I have no idea how to go on. Maybe you can help me. This is my first question, so please let me know if I need to be more specific or you need more code or anything.
thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem with this question is that it has to many information on it. We have to seperate the question to little pieces. First of all, the order id is the same for two different products, is this normal?

Comment: olso group by or distinct would not help because you have different products with the same order id. You need to create an array with a key of order_id and values of products

Comment: hey, you're right, i'm just really confused and so i wrote down everything at once.
with the order number: yes, so when a custumer buys something, the relation "kundenbestellungen" creates an unique ID for each item, but also for each order a number. so if you buy three items at once, each item gets a different ID, but they all get the same order number, because you bought them together. if you buy two things later, each also gets a new ID, but they also get the same order number (but its a different order number than the first one). do you know what I mean?

Comment: Ok perfect. From the first part of code do you get anything on your screen? or the values are empty?

Comment: the first part shows the table like in the first picture I posted. 
so in each table row it shows the order number, the custumers name, the products etc.. but it becomes very unclear because in the next row it shows the same order number, the same custumers name and the only thing thats different is the product. this goes on until the next order number starts.

Comment: ok now we know that we are getting some values from the db. You want to show on your table each order number but show olso all the products that is connected to this order number in one row right?

Comment: yes, or like this:

order number      product 1       custumer
and below product 1 the next one (product 2)

Comment: In this case you need to use an array. You need to store all the values inside this array and later make a foreach loop for every element in the array

Comment: okay, thank you already. I'll try it! hopefully I'll understand how to do it.

Comment: ok perfect. If you have any problems with the array creation tell me